# #wordpress. How to store same meta key values in array as $postid => $metavalue in database

Tags: wordpress

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyj3p.jpg)I have created a custom metabox with 3 fields `author`, `date` and `price`.

But when value is stored in the database, meta key of `author`, `date` and `price` is stored separately for different posts. I want to store all posts having same meta key in one field as `$postid` as key and its metavalues as value in array.

Here is my code:

```html
/**
 * Register meta boxes.
 */
function hcf_register_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'hcf-1', __( 'Hello Custom Field', 'hcf' ), 'hcf_display_callback', 'post' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'hcf_register_meta_boxes' );

/**
 * Meta box display callback.
 *
 * @param WP_Post $post Current post object.
 */
function hcf_display_callback( $post ) { ?>
     <!-- echo "Hello Custom Field"; -->
<div class="hcf_box">
    <style scoped>
        .hcf_box{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            grid-column-gap: 20px;
        }
        .hcf_field{
            display: contents;
        }
    </style>
    <p class="meta-options hcf_field">
     
        <label for="hcf_author">Author</label>

        <input id="hcf_author"
            type="text"
            name="hcf_author"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hcf_author', true ) ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p class="meta-options hcf_field">
        <label for="hcf_published_date">Published Date</label>
        <input id="hcf_published_date"
            type="date"
            name="hcf_published_date"
           value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hcf_published_date', true ) ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p class="meta-options hcf_field">
        <label for="hcf_price">Price</label>
        <input id="hcf_price"
            type="number"
            name="hcf_price"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hcf_price', true ) ); ?>">
    </p>
</div>
<?php }
/**
 * Save meta box content.
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID
 */
function hcf_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        $post_id = $parent_id;
    }

    $fields = [
        'hcf_author'
        'hcf_published_date',
        'hcf_price',
    ];
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $field, $_POST ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $field, sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$field] ) );
        }
     }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'hcf_save_meta_box' );
```

Comment: How do you want your array to look like?

Comment: I want my all post author in hcf_author meta key ,all published date in hcf_published date meta key and allprices of post in hcf_price meta key.i just dont want meta key to be repeated in post meta table.Suppose inside hcf_author meta key array there must be author and its post ids key and value.each and every posts field should be stored in same array not in different post ids with same meta key.Hope i am able to understand u.